# MS-Access...Create a new record using last record info on form

Tags: ms-access

Inventory DB...

Have an entry form with multiple combo boxes, an add entry button and exit button. Normally, I would just use (DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec) on click for the add button to add the record and clear the form for the next entry. But the user wants to have the last record information show up after the initial entry is added, (which I have accomplished), to keep from re-doing some fields over and if any fields are changed, to then be able to add that changed record without changing the last record info that appeared on the form.

Comment: We love that you're here and this is too vague for us to help you. Show us your programming problem so we can jump in.

Comment: After update of a record, set the _DefaultValue_ of the relevant fields to their content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing Textbox.DefaultValue in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845816/changing-textbox-defaultvalue-in-access)

Comment: This might work, I’ll give it a try and let you know...