# Access 2016: Entering multiple values in a cell and saving it as multiple records in the same table

Tags: ms-access

I have imported an existing excel file and created it as table 'Product' in access. It already has rows of existing data. I have created a form based on the table for data entry.

I would like to enter multiple values in the ProductNo cell separated by a comma ( as shown below)

| PID (PK - Autonum) | PCR | ProductNo | Title | Unit | Dept | Date | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | PCR1 | p210en, p213es, p217er | PCR1 title description | 2 | D1 | 1/23/21 | fdsfsdf |

and saving the record, it has to split the cell values and save it as multiple records in the backend product table.

| PID (PK - Autonum) | PCR | ProductNo | Title | Unit | Dept | Date | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | PCR1 | p210en | PCR1 title description | 2 | D1 | 01/23/2021 | fdsfsdf |
|  | PCR1 | p213es | PCR1 title description | 2 | D1 | 01/23/2021 | fdsfsdf |
|  | PCR1 | p217er | PCR1 title description | 2 | D1 | 01/23/2021 | fdsfsdf |

I don't want to edit the existing data in Product. It correctly reflects only one value in the ProductNo. I want to update only the values entered in the form.

I have looked for similar vba codes and found ones that modifies data in the existing table.

I have worked with SQL before but not much with Access/VBA code. I have programming knowledge. Any help is appreciated. Thank you :)

**Updated -- Possible Solution**:

So this is what I have done. I have a created a temporary table 'TempProduct' that I have used to input the data and when I click on save button, I have the following vba code that splits the cell data in multiple records and adds it to the original table.

```
enter code here
```

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command11_Click()  

Dim db As Database  
Dim rs1 As Recordset  
Dim rs2 As Recordset  
Set db = CurrentDb()  
Dim sqlStr, fieldStr As String  
Dim i As Integer  

sqlStr = "Select PCR, ProductNo, Title, Unit, Dept, Date, Comments from TempProduct"  
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(sqlStr)  
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("Product")  
Do While Not rs1.EOF  
fieldStr = rs1.Fields(1)  
 
If InStr(fieldStr, ",") > 0 Then  
myString = Split(fieldStr, ",")  
For i = LBound(myString) To UBound(myString)  
rs2.AddNew  
rs2!PCR = rs1!ECRNo  
rs2!ProductNo = myString(i)  
rs2!Title = rs1!Title  
rs2!Unit = rs1!Unit  
rs2!Dept = rs1!Dept  
rs2!Date = rs1!Date  
rs2!Comments=rs1!Comments  
rs2.Update  
Next i  
Else  
rs2.AddNew  
rs2!PCR = rs1!ECRNo  
rs2!ProductNo = rs1!ProductNo  
rs2!Title = rs1!Title  
rs2!Unit = rs1!Unit  
rs2!Dept = rs1!Dept  
rs2!Date = rs1!Date  
rs2!Comments=rs1!Comments  
rs2.Update  
End If  

rs1.MoveNext  
Loop  
DoCmd.RunSQL ("Delete * from TempProduct")  
End Sub
```

And it kind of works. Though the multiple records are pushed from the form into the product table only when a new record is added again. i.e. the first record entered in the form are split and entered into the product table only after the second set of records are entered in the form.

Any suggestions as how I can push the records immediately. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: If you have zero knowledge in VBA, then an answer would have to include a VBA tutorial

Comment: I have worked with SQL before but not much with Access/VBA code. I have programming knowledge.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, the table is your question is not properly formatted. Have a look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/138661) for how to format a table. You can use the "Edit" link below your question to modify it.

Comment: You would be better off to design a form for normal data entry. Enter each product number in a separate record. No code required. If you really must do as you describe, then write code that uses Split() function to parse CSV string to an array and loop through array to write records. Be sure to deal with spaces if entered between elements. But beware, this approach will be source of great frustration for you and users. Just forget one comma and the house of cards falls. Since your question does not show any code with an issue, it is not suited to SO.

Comment: Enter CSV string into an UNBOUND textbox on an UNBOUND form. One of your tables is now correctly formatted.

Comment: Oh ok. Will correct the other table. This is my first very post. I have bound the form to the table as I use the same form for viewing/finding records and also individual fields in it.

Comment: If you enter CSV string to bound form and bound textbox, then you create a new record with that string. I don't think you want that. Do normal data entry with BOUND form and controls. Enter each product into its own record. If you want other data to repeat, use VBA to 'carry forward' those data to each new record. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845816/changing-textbox-defaultvalue-in-access

Comment: However, repeating so much data indicates a non-optimized data structure - not adequately normalized.

Comment: I have updated the original post with a possible solution. Any suggestions/improvements will be appreciated. Thank you!