# Keep combobox in the form header constant for new records

Tags: ms-access, combobox, continuous-forms

I am trying to make a group training form where I can select a course from a combobox (placed in the form header), and add many employees, using another combobox, in the detail section of the continuous form. Problem is, as soon as I move to new record, the course value in the combobox changes. How do I keep the course combobox constant?

Thanks

Comment: Course combobox is bound to field? Why would you not expect value to change? It should be empty for new record unless DefaultValue property is set. Possibly need to use a form/subform arrangement. This question lacks detail and does not have code for analysis and really is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Otherwise, bound combobox belongs in Detail section and use code to carry forward selected course to new record by setting DefaultValue property in combobox AfterUpdate event.

Comment: @June7 Thank you for your reply. I do not have a code to share otherwise I would. Course combobox is bound because the form then needs to save the records in a table i.e., which employees attended which course on a particular date. If I leave the course combo unbound, it does not get registered in the table. 

What you said about carrying default value makes sense. But I am not sure how would I implement that in vba? Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Use a form/subform arrangement and no code needed. Otherwise, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845816/changing-textbox-defaultvalue-in-access

Comment: Thank you, @June7. Precisely what I was after :)